Why can't my iPhone connect to Samba any longer?
My iPhone's Files-app used to connect to my standalone Samba-server (running on a FreeBSD-14 computer). It was not entirely worry-free, but it worked most of the time.
Not any more. With Samba-4.19.4 (and the just-installed 4.19.6), I get the "Unknown Error" message on the phone, and the following entries in the Samba's own logs on the server:
rpcd_classic version 4.19.6 started.
svcctl_init_winreg: Could not open SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services - NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
dcesrv_init_ep_server: Failed to init endpoint server 'svcctl': NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
register_ep_server: dcesrv_init_ep_server(svcctl) failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

Now, testparm does warn of two deprecated options -- kept for the sake of the old entertainment set-top box, that needs them:
lpcfg_do_global_parameter: WARNING: The "lanman auth" option is deprecated
lpcfg_do_global_parameter: WARNING: The "client use spnego" option is deprecated
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

The [global] section reads:
[global]
        client min protocol = NT1
        dns proxy = No
        lanman auth = Yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        netbios aliases = older mucholder
        ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
        security = USER
        server min protocol = NT1
        server string = Mumu Samba Server
        unix charset = koi8-u
        workgroup = MUMU
        readdir_attr:aapl_rsize = yes
        readdir_attr:aapl_max_access = yes
        readdir_attr:aapl_finder_info = yes
        fruit:zero_file_id = yes
        fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
        fruit:veto_appledouble = no
        fruit:posix_rename = yes
        fruit:nfs_aces = no
        fruit:model = MacSamba
        fruit:metadata = stream
        fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
        fruit:copyfile = yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        hosts allow = 192.168.1. 127.
        vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr

Running smbclient -L does not list any shares -- indeed, there is a warning of some sort:
lpcfg_do_global_parameter: WARNING: The "lanman auth" option is deprecated
lpcfg_do_global_parameter: WARNING: The "client use spnego" option is deprecated
Password for [MUMU\mi]:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
cli_rpc_pipe_open_noauth: rpc_pipe_bind for pipe srvsvc failed with error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        MUMU                 FUFU

Is that it? Is iPhone looking for a list of shares and is unable to get them -- even though several are marked as "guest ok" and "browseable".
My smb4.conf hasn't changed substantially in years, what am I doing wrong?
